# Why does $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ have the countable chain condition while $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif}$ does not

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, product-space

Let  $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ be countable product of $\mathbb{R}$ with the product topology, $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ be countable product of $\mathbb{R}$ with the uniform topology. I wish to show that:

> Show that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ has the countable chain
>   condition, and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif}$ does not.

Recall: A topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ has the countable chain condition (CCC) if there are no uncountable collections of pairwise disjoint open sets (PDNO sets)

I am confused why the proof that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif}$ is not CCC doesn't work for $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$

---

**Proof 1: $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif}$ is not CCC**

- Take the collection of sequences that maps from the naturals to the
  integers $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N} = \{x: x: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}
     \}$
- Since $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif}$ is metrizable with the uniform
  metric $$d_u(x,y) = \sup\limits_{n \in
     \mathbb{N}}\{\min\{d(x_n,y_n),1\}\} =\sup\limits_{n \in
     \mathbb{N}}\{d(x_n,y_n) \wedge 1\} $$
- Define the open ball $B_\epsilon(x) = \{y \in
     \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif} | d_u(x,y) < \epsilon\}$
- Then take $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2}$, we have $x \in B_\frac{1}{2}(x)
     \subset \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $B_\frac{1}{2}(x) \cap
     B_\frac{1}{2}(y) = \varnothing, \forall x \neq y$
- Since $|\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_1$ is uncountable, therefore
  the set of balls defined above is uncountable. Specifically,
  $\{B_\frac{1}{2}(x)| x \in \mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\}$ is uncountable.
- This consititutes a collection of uncountable PDNO sets, hence $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{unif}$ is not CCC.

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \nwarrow$

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad $ **This proof is unverified**

---

My question is why doesn't the above imply that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ is not CCC?

Recall that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ is metrizable via $$d_p(x,y) = \sup\limits_{n \in
   \mathbb{N}}\{\dfrac{\min\{d(x_n,y_n),1\}}{n}\} =\sup\limits_{n \in
   \mathbb{N}}\{\dfrac{d(x_n,y_n)\wedge 1}{n} \} $$

Then fix $\epsilon$, $B_\epsilon^p(x) \subseteq B\epsilon^u(x)$.

Doesn't this mean we can put even open smaller ball around a given sequence $x : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{N}$?

This means we still have an uncountable collection of PDNO set in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

---

Can someone provide a quick reason as to why this is? Is there a quick proof showing that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}_\text{prod}$ is CCC?

Comment: I think you got an inclusion backward. $d_p$ is smaller than $d_u$, so its $\epsilon$-ball is bigger: $B^p_\epsilon(x)\supseteq B^u_\epsilon(x)$.

Comment: Also, although $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ is uncountable, the statement that its cardinality is $\aleph_1$ is the continuum hypothesis, which is not provable from the usual axioms of set theory.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hi can you elaborate on the inclusion? Why do I keep making this mistake? How do you know which ball is contained in which

Comment: To say that $y$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x$ as measured by the small metric (i.e., $d_p(x,y)<\epsilon$) isn't saying much, since $d_p$ is small, so it's easy for $y$ to satisfy this condition. To say that $y$ is within $\epsilon$ of $x$ as measured by the big metric (i.e., $d_u(x,y)<\epsilon$) says a lot, since $d_u$ is small, so it's hard for $y$ to satisfy this condition.  More $y$'s satisfy the easy condition than the difficult one.

Comment: Another way to remember which way the inclusion goes is to remember that the distance between two points as measured in miles is much less than the distance between the same points as measured in inches, and a ball of radius 3 miles is way bigger than a ball of radius 3 inches.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Good catch on $\aleph_1$ btw

Comment: If $x_n-y_n=n/2$ for every $n$ then $y\in B_{2/3}^p(x)$ but $d_u(x,y)=1$ so $y\not \in B_{2/3}^u(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}_{\text{unif}}$ is not c.c.c. doesn't carry over to $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}_{\text{prod}}$ because of the structure of the open balls in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}_{\text{prod}}$. What you have essentially done is construct, for each $\mathbf x \in \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$, a uniform open ball about $\mathbf x$ that does not contain any other element of $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$. The same cannot be done for the product topology.

For suppose that $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots) \in \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then there must be an $n$ such that $\frac 1n < \varepsilon$. Now consider $\mathbf y = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1}+1,x_{n+2}+1,\ldots) \in \mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$. Note that for $i \leq n$ we have that $\min(|x_i-y_i|,1) = \min(|x_1-x_i|,1) = \min(0,1) = 0$, and for $i > n$ we have that $\min(|x_i-y_i|,1) = \min(|x_i-(x_i+1)|,1) = \min(1,1) = 1$, and so it follows that
$$\begin{align}
d_p(\mathbf x , \mathbf y) 
&= \sup_{i \in \mathbb N} \{ \frac{\min ( d(x_i,y_i),1 )}n \} \\
%&= \sup \{ 
%\frac{\min(|x_1-x_1|,1)}1, \frac{\min(|x_2-x_2|,1)}2 , \ldots , %\frac{\min(|x_n-x_n|,1)}n , \frac{\min(|x_{n+1}-(x_{n+1}+1)|,1)}{n+1},  %\frac{\min(|x_{n+2}-(x_{n+2}+1)|,1)}{n+2}, \ldots \} \\
&= \sup \{ 0, 0, \ldots, 0 , \tfrac{1}{n+1}, \tfrac{1}{n+2}, \ldots \} \\
&= \frac{1}{n+1} \\
&< \varepsilon
\end{align}$$

So it follows that every $d_p$-ball about an element of $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$ contains another element of $\mathbb Z^{\mathbb N}$.

(This, of course, does not prove that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}_{\text{prod}}$ is c.c.c., but shows that the same argument cannot be used to show that it isn't c.c.c.)

---

Quick proofs that $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}_{\text{prod}}$ is c.c.c. include the following:

- By the [Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery  Theorem](http://planetmath.org/hewittmarczewskipondiczerytheorem) $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}_{\text{prod}}$ is actually separable, and so it is c.c.c. since all separable spaces are c.c.c.
- It can be shown that a product space $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is c.c.c. iff for each finite $F \subseteq I$ the product $\prod_{i \in F} X_i$ is c.c.c. (See Theorem 2 on [Product of Spaces with Countable Chain Condition](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/product-of-spaces-with-countable-chain-condition/) from Dan Ma's Topology Blog.) In this case we have $I = \mathbb N$ and $X_i = \mathbb R$ for each $i$. For each finite $F \subseteq I$ the product $\prod_{i \in F} X_i$ is just the Euclidean $|F|$-space, which is clearly c.c.c. (again, use separability if you must).